# Rails: Model property, value is not displayed on view mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model but one of its property is not displaying its value.

`<% @medical_history.neonatalcourse %>`

I already check my sqllite file and the value is there. So I am sure that I am saving the field. The problem is it not displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use an equal sign with your tag to tell it to print the output of the ruby statement into the view.  The version without the "=" is for when you don't wish to have a statement print its value into the page.

```
<%= @medical_history.neonatalcourse %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I copy paste it from an if statement :)